# Repeated application of simple moving average

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, summation, algorithms, recursion

To simplify slightly, let
$$S(t)=\sum_{j=-L}^L y(t+j)$$
I am looking for a single-summation formula for m repeated applications of this filter. For example, if the filter is applied twice to the sequence of y(t),
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{j=-L}^L S(t+j)&=&S(t-L)+S(t-L+1)+\cdots S(t)+S(t+1)+\cdots S(t+L)
\nonumber\\
&=&y(t-2L)+2y(t-2L+1)+\cdots+(2L+1)y(t)+\cdots+2y(t+2L-1)+y(t+2L)\nonumber\\
&=&\sum_{j=-2L}^{2L} (2L+1-|j|)y(t+j)
\end{eqnarray}
It seems likely that this has been published - a reference would be welcome.

Comment: So you are convoluting $y$ and $m$ copies of $x\mapsto{[|x|\leq L]}$?